# How can I redirect to another server's web socket?

Tags: django, redirect, rust, websocket

I am currently building a chat server using Rust. I tried to authenticate with the user's digest token that existed in the existing postgresql, but it failed because of the openssl problem. Therefore, I would like to authenticate the user through the existing django authentication authority, and when authentication is successful, I would like to redirect it to the rust chat server to make the service available.

[My composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Os9.png)

```py
async def redirect(websocket: WebSocket, *args, **kwargs):
    await websocket.accept()
    return Response(status=HTTP_301_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
```

I tried redirecting from django to websocket, but failed.

How can I authenticate with django and get access to the rust websocket server? I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is a better way than redirect. If I have to redirect, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to redirect. I googled hard, but I didn't find anything out.

Comment: You can't redirect with websockets.

Comment: @Evert That's sad... Then how can I go to the rust websocket server after authenticating with django server? If this is not possible, would it be better to create a separate authentication server?

Comment: I assume you need some kind of api / access_token / bearer token from Django and then use that to connect to the websocket. Can't you do that in 2 distinct steps?

Comment: @Evert Currently, my django app is authenticating token through django knox, and I would like to connect to a rust websocket server that is not related to django.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import permissions


class ClassName(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("https://host:port/websocket_url")
```

I solved this problem with the code above. Using `https://` instead of `wss://`, (Because I'm using ssl, I used https instead of http.) it was accessible through the web socket url. I don't know if this is right